# Merge Cells Data with Multiple rows or New Lines

Tags: google-sheets

*I hope to have a formula that can concatenate A and B columns but each texts within cells shall still sit next to each other.

[image: Ideal Result in Column D]

Here is the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14OKObszKg5TiIYeSr929PmCi7WDKciQ_A4kOFTEeZdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try-

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),INDEX(SPLIT(A3,CHAR(10))&SPLIT(B3,CHAR(10))))
```

[image]